# Unable to authenticate using http Dart package to Azure DevOps Rest API

Tags: flutter, dart, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to call the Azure DevOps REST API with the HTTP DART package to get a list of projects. However, whenever I call the API, I get a 401 error with the message "Unauthorized." So far, I have tried several different header formats and regenerated my personal access token numerous times. I've attached my code below, but I wonder if my HTTP header should be in a different format?

```
final st = "key";
final bytes = utf8. encode (str);
final base64Str = base64. encode (bytes);
print (base64Str);

var response = await http.get (
    Uri.parse('https://dev.azure.com/companyrd/_apis/projects?api-version=2.0&Authorization=Basic%BASE64PATSTRING'),
    headers: {
        HttpHeaders. authorizationHeader: "Basic, " + base64Str,
    }
);

print(response.body);
```

Comment: Basic auth normally needs `username:password` encoded. It seems unlikely azure would be using basic auth anyway. Don't they give an example of how to use this "personal access token"? You may find it useful to download Postman and try using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
headers: {
       HttpHeaders. authorizationHeader: "Basic " + base64Str,
   }
```

**Remove ',' after Basic and try it again**

Comment: Sadly that results in the message of "Non-Authoritative Information" for the reasonPhrase and the statusCode of 203. In the response's body, I get the HTML version of the sign-in page to DevOps. I'm using print(response.body);
to see the output.

Comment: Never mind, your answer was correct, thanks! I also realized that the base64Str that my code created wasn't accurate. However, I could get the correct string from Postman and paste it in.

Comment: Thanks mate, kindly vote my answer :)